# JavaScript indentation messes up after some inactivity

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Whenever I leave the IDE running for a while, but don't really touch a JavaScript file that's open (or while I'm debugging), the indentation tends to mess up for some reason. It doesn't affect existing code, just when I'm writing new code. It will make weird jumps and assumptions and seemingly indents completely random.

The only fix I've found so far is restarting the IDE, or manually indent every line every time it auto-indents. It's pretty annoying since I have to load a large solution from the company network, so restarting the IDE is taking a lot of time out of my day.

Anyone know what could be causing this, or how this might be fixed?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated but did you know that [Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/products/visual-studio-community-vs) is a free version of the Professional SKU with all the bells and whistles?

Comment: No, I didn't know that. Unfortunately, I can't use it for commercial purposes at my job. I'll be sure to get it at home for personal use, though!

Comment: Since Express don't allow any plugins to be installed, my guess would be that there are some automagic settings i the IDE that does autoformatting. For C# a setting like that would generally reformat code when you entered a closing brace `}`, perhaps worth looking at but I'm sure you've been all over any settings already.

Comment: Yeah it's exactly like that, except that it works just fine and actually helps me a lot. Until it bugs out and goes all over the place :(